# Using sed to edit milter-greylist config file

Tags: bash, sed

Virtualmin supports manually configuring domains for email rate limiting. I would like to create a script to automatically add the domain to the milter-greylist and define its rate limit per hour automatically.

When a domain (example.com) is set for rate-limiting of 500 emails per hour, it adds the following three lines in `/etc/milter-greylist/greylist.conf`:

```
ratelimit "domain_14014450697382" rcpt 500 / 1h
racl blacklist from /.*@example.com/ ratelimit "domain_14014450697382" msg "Message quota exceeded"
racl whitelist from /.*@example.com`
```

Those three lines are inserted above `racl whitelist default`. The string of numbers after the domain is the domain ID, and can be found by executing:

```
virtualmin list-domains --domain $VIRTUALSERVER_DOM --id-only
```

I’m trying to insert those three lines when a server is created, and remove the three lines when a server is deleted. I have pretty rudimentary scripting skills and came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

# script is executed when changes are made to server

## Add new domain to milter-greylist for rate limiting
if [ "$VIRTUALSERVER_ACTION" = "CREATE_DOMAIN" ]; then
ID=$(virtualmin list-domains --domain $VIRTUALSERVER_DOM --id-only) &&
sed -i '/racl whitelist default/ a\ratelimit "domain_"$ID rcpt 500 / 1h\n
racl blacklist from /.*@$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM/ ratelimit "domain_"$ID msg "Message quota exceeded"\n
racl whitelist from /.*@$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM/\n' /etc/milter-greylist/greylist.conf 
fi

## Remove domain from milter-greylist on domain deletion
if [ "$VIRTUALSERVER_ACTION" = "DELETE_DOMAIN" ]; then
ID=$(virtualmin list-domains --domain $VIRTUALSERVER_DOM --id-only) &&
sed -i '/$ID/d' /etc/milter-greylist/greylist.conf &&
sed -i '/$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM/d' /etc/milter-greylist/greylist.conf
fi
```

which results in:

```
racl whitelist default
ratelimit "domain_"$ID rcpt 500 / 1h

ratelimit "domain_"$ID rcpt 500 / 1h

/etc/milter-greylisting/greylisting.conf
```

Can someone advise what I need to fix?

Answer (score 2):

You used `'` quotes in your `sed` expression and so bash expansion didn't happen. The following script should work.

```
## Add new domain to milter-greylist for rate limiting
if [ "$VIRTUALSERVER_ACTION" = "CREATE_DOMAIN" ]; then
  ID=$(virtualmin list-domains --domain $VIRTUALSERVER_DOM --id-only)
  sed -i "/racl whitelist default/i \ratelimit \"domain_$ID\" rcpt 500 / 1h\nracl blacklist from /.*@$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM/ ratelimit \"domain_$ID\" msg \"Message quota exceeded\"\nracl whitelist from /.*@$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM/\n" /etc/milter-greylist/greylist.conf 
fi

## Remove domain from milter-greylist on domain deletion
if [ "$VIRTUALSERVER_ACTION" = "DELETE_DOMAIN" ]; then
  ID=$(virtualmin list-domains --domain $VIRTUALSERVER_DOM --id-only)
  sed -i "/$ID/d" /etc/milter-greylist/greylist.conf
  sed -i "/$VIRTUALSERVER_DOM/d" /etc/milter-greylist/greylist.conf
fi
```

tested in `GNU sed version 4.2.1`. Hope that helps.

Comment: On domain deletion, the first line added: ratelimit "domain_14018009701093" rcpt 500 / 1h, is not deleted.  Can you advise on changes to the line: sed -i "/$ID/d" /etc/milter-greylist/greylist.conf to delete that line?

Comment: I tested the deletion too before adding the answer. Isn't it working?